# Scala - factoring out constructors

Tags: scala, closures

i seem to have a relatively simple problem: I do have some code that downloads a file from http and performs an unzip operation. these 2 codes seem pretty similar:

```
  def downloadFile(url: URL, filename: String) {
    var out: OutputStream = null
    var in: InputStream = null

    try {
      val outPutFile = new File(filename)
      if (outPutFile.exists())
      {
        outPutFile.delete()
      }
      val uc = url.openConnection()
      val connection = uc.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
      in = connection.getInputStream()
      out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))

      copy(in, out)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println(e.printStackTrace())
    }

    out.close()
    in.close()

  }

    def unzipFile(file: File): String = {
    var out: OutputStream = null

    val outputFileName = "uncompressed" + file.getName()
    println("trying to acess " + file.getName() + file.getAbsoluteFile())
    val in = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
    val outfile = new File(outputFileName)
    if (outfile.exists()) {
      outfile.delete()
    }
    out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName)

    copy(in, out)
    in.close()
    out.close()
    return outputFileName

  }

     def copy(in: InputStream, out: OutputStream) {
    val buffer: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](1024)
    var sum: Int = 0
    Iterator.continually(in.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach({ n => out.write(buffer, 0, n); (sum += buffer.length); println(sum + " written to output "); })
  }
```

is there a way to rewrite the download / unzip method into one method and to factor out the constrcutors to achieve a dependency - injection like behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are asking about is the scenario where you have functions that have the same needs for the beginning and/or end, but the middle part can differ on a per call basis.  If that's what you are looking for then solve that problem by passing in the middle part as a function like this:

```
def doSomething(func: => Unit){
  //Do common stuff here

  //Invoke passed in behavior
  func

  //Do common end stuff here
}
```

Then you could use it in another function like this:

```
def downloadFile(url: URL, filename: String) {
  doSomething{
    //You have access to url and filename here due to closure
  }
}
```

This way, if the was common concerns/functionality between these two functions (`downloadFile` and `unzipFile`), you could capture that in `doSomething` and then just allow the calling function to specify the behavior specific to that function.

This patten is similar to the Loan Pattern and could also probably be related to the Template Method from the OO world